# progress bar/loader/spinner for map.locate

Tags: leaflet, gps, progress

Im using Leaflet.Control.GPS (https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps) to locate the users location.

How to add a progress indicator, or a spinner (or some other UX hint) which should appear only when "map.locate" is trying to find the current position of the user?

I already added via Leaflet.Loading (https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.loading) a spinner to my map, but only works when loading tiles.

Maybe it is possible to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add a progress indicator. There is no way to predict how much time a [geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) query will take.

In order to add a spinner, or any other "waiting message" or UX hint, just display it when starting the geolocation query, and hide it when the query is finished, e.g.:

```
spinner.show();
map.once('locationfound locationerror', function(ev){
    spinner.hide();
});
map.locate(locateOptions);
```

The specific way of showing and hiding that UX element is up to you, depending on what you want (a button, a transparent overlay, a "toast" notification, etc etc etc), but the map-related logic should look like that.

Comment: this geolocate plugin makes it possible: https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol. but it is not as accurate and smooth as Leaflet.Control.GPS (https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps).

Comment: But that adds a *spinner*, no a *progress indicator*. The wording of your questions suggest that you want to be aware of *progress*.

Comment: a spinner would be fine too

Comment: Please note that I've edited your question and my answer to reflect that.

Comment: any sample or hint how to integrate a font-awesome spinner like in github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol. to github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps.?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question with almost exactly the same requirement. You can use the Leaflet.Loading plugin to display a spinner and control it with map events...

To display the spinner:
`map.fire('dataloading');`

To hide it:
`map.fire('dataload');`

Combine this with the logic in @ivansanchez  answer.